# C# Async void doesn't execute all lines

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a problem. I created this async void:

```
private async void AddImageToPreview(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        var image = (Image)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1];

        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("mysite.org/" + App.TemplateSource + (string)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1]);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);

        float x = (float)MemeCanvas.Width / 2;
        float y = (float)MemeCanvas.Height / 2;

        int NewDictionaryKey = SelectedMemeTemplateIDs.Count;
        MemesOnCanvas NewMeme = new MemesOnCanvas
        {
            //ResourceID = resourceID
        };

        SelectedMemeTemplateIDs.Add(NewDictionaryKey, NewMeme);
        UpdateMemeTemplateCollection();
        MemeCanvas.InvalidateSurface();                
    }
}
```

That I call using this line:

```
HomePage.SelectedMemeCollection.CollectionChanged += AddImageToPreview;
```

Now I have set a breakpoint on the first line in that void: `var image = (Image)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1];` and that point gets hit, but when I set a breakpoint on the second line: `var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();`, it never gets hit...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Also, I see you're casting `e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1]` to both `Image` and `string`, what does your collection actually contain?

Comment: That was what I was testing, but I can't cause the code never hits the breakpoint

Comment: The collection contains a FileName and an Image. `HomePage.SelectedMemeCollection.Add(FileName, image);`. Now I want the FileName at the end of my url and the image as `var image`

Comment: What is the actual type of your collection? Is it a dictionary or something else?

Comment: I created a custom class, so it is a ObservableDictionary. Then I can use the CollectionChanged!

Comment: it can be possible if `var image = (Image)e.NewItems` raises an exception and you do not have `catch unhanded exception option` turned on in the VS. Please change it to `var image = e.NewItems.LastOrDefault();` and try again. In the next line you are casting e.NewItems item to the string `(string)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1]` - it will not work.

Comment: change it to async task

Comment: Great. You should be able to retrieve your Image by typing `e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1].Value`, and your file path by typing `e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1].Key`.

Comment: you can put breakpoint on the first line and hit F10 (step over by default) to check will the first line work or not

Comment: @Emanuel Vintila, It says `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'`?

Comment: The problem is that you're doing an invalid cast. Without seeing the implementation of your custom Observable Dictionary we can't know which is the proper type that you should cast to. It may be `KeyValuePair<string, Image>`, or it might be something else.

Comment: Here is my custom Dictionary: https://gist.github.com/kzu/cfe3cb6e4fe3efea6d24

Comment: This is the important line `CollectionChanged (this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs (NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
    new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> (key, value)));` You're calling the event with a `new KeyValuePair`. So to get your image and string in your event handler you must do
`var pair = (KeyValuePair<string, Image>) e.NewItems.Last();
var image = pair.Value;
var path = pair.Key;`

Comment: The behavior you observe may be related to the debugging capabilities of Visual Studio, and not to the characteristics of .NET Framework or the C# compiler. The Visual Studio's breakpoints are there to help you, but can also occasionally create new problems on their own. Especially when you are debugging parallel or asynchronous code.

Comment: Thank you Emanuel Vintalia!! This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom dictionary implementation calls the event handlers with an event that contains a list of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. To retrieve the last added element you must do:

```cs
var pair = (KeyValuePair<string, Image>) e.NewItems.Last();
var path = pair.Key;
var image = pair.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to check what is stored in the `e.NewItems` collection

It can be possible if `var image = (Image)e.NewItems[]` raises an exception and you do not have `catch unhanded exception option` turned on in the VS.

Please change it to `var image = e.NewItems.LastOrDefault();` and try again.

In the next line you are casting `e.NewItems[]` item to the string `(string)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1]` - it will not work for sure

Please check what is stored in the `e.NewItems` to be sure that you are casting properly.

what is type for item for `var item = e.NewItems.LastOrDefault()` ?